# searching and creating matches over mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to do a search across a mongo collection and then update any matches as a result of the search. This allows future searches to only run across items that aren't matches.

I have ~20k `searchItem` objects to go through and searching across ~4M items.

the collections are as follows

```
SearchItem {
    _id
    valueA
    valueB        
}

Item {
    matchIds
    valueA
    valueB
    valueC
}
```

My query is doing

```
db.Item.update( { 
    valueA: SearchItem.valueA,
    valueB: SearchItem.valueB,
    matchIds: { 
                   $ne: SearchItem._id
              }                                  
 },
 { 
      $addToSet: 
                 {
                      matchIds: SearchItem._id
                 } 
 }, false, true)
```

This works; however this query takes too long to run, as it is finding up to 300K matches on a  single item. It then locks up and causes timeout exceptions basically blowing up the system.

I am interested in if there is a better way to do these searches while retaining knowledge of what has been searched previously or if there is a better way to do these updates such that the time it takes is reduced avoiding massive locks.

I have an index on `valueA`, `valueB` and `valueC`, the query will not always be just `valueA & valueB` so placing composite indexes for faster searches will result in propertyNumber^2 indexes, which isn't nice.

`MongoDb` version being used is V2.4.9 and the official C# driver V1.8.3.

Comment: Is there any way you can find any pattern of your query? Compound index also supports query of [prefixes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes)

Comment: Is not the `{$ne }` on matchId's redundant? Considering that `$addToSet` will not add something that is already there and only add where it is not. Hence "a Set". This question might be better explained with your "use case" if you are looking for a better solution. But a compound index on `valueA` and `valueB` seems to be all the matching that is needed. It still seems like you are doing some work that may be handled in a better way though.

Comment: With regards to the prefixes, this is something I've considered; however the form of the data is not well defined currently and so finding a pattern would simply be a guess. The different objects we are searching across is not static so valueA-valueC could become valueA-valueZ. The search is not what is causing the issue though, **it is the update that is the primary problem**.